# php script not running via crontab runs fine manually

Tags: php, cron

My script is working fine when I run it into browser but not working when I run it using cron

```
require_once('/home/dekh/public_html/track/classes/affiliate.class.php');
require_once('/home/dekh/public_html/track/classes/offer.class.php');
require_once('/home/dekh/public_html/track/classes/merchant.class.php');
require_once('/home/dekh/public_html/track/includes/emails.php');
$mer=new Merchant;
$aff=new Affiliate;
$offer=new Offer;
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
mail('my email address', 'My Subject', $message);
```

I get mail when I run it in browser

Here how I've added it in cron

```
wget /home/dekh/public_html/track/includes/cron_for_conversions_mail.php
php /home/dekh/public_html/track/includes/cron_for_conversions_mail.php
```

I've tried it both ways php /home.. and wget /home...

Please suggest thanks

Comment: commonly this is an environment problem. PATH variable, Access rights (which user is running the cron?), certain environment variables like TZ, LOCALE, ... Check the environment when running from console and when running from cron

Comment: Actually I'm running another cron on same server and everything is same
php /home/dekh/public_html/db_backup/back_up_db.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wget url but not a local file

just like:

```
  http://127.0.0.1/cron_for_conversions_mail.php
```

Comment: I don't know why php php /home/dekh/public_html/track/includes/cron_for_conversions_mail.php is not working but  php /home/dekh/public_html/db_backup/back_up_db.php is working for me.

But as @eric_zyh suggested to wget the url it worked for me thanks a lot for pointing out what I was doing wrong here.